# how do I setInterval to call a function within a class

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

I have a class like:

```
function run(){
this.interval;
this.start = function(){
    this.interval = setInterval('this.draw()',1000);
};
this.draw = function(){
    //some code
};} var run = new run(); run.start();
```

however I can't seem to reference/call `this.draw()` within the setInterval, it says `this.draw()` is not a function, and if I remove the quotes it says useless setInterval call, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The value of `this` is set depending on how a function is called. When you call a function as a constructor using `new` then `this` will refer to the object being created. Similarly when you call a function with dot notation like `run.start()` then `this` will refer to `run`. But by the time the code run by the `setInterval` is called `this` doesn't mean what you think. What you can do is save a reference to `this` and then use that reference, like the following:

```
function Run(){
  var self = this;

  self.start = function(){
    self.interval = setInterval(function() { self.draw(); },1000);
  };

  self.draw = function(){
    //some code
  };
}

var run = new Run();

run.start();
```

Note also that you've created a function called `run` *and* a variable called `run` - you need to give them different names. In my code (bearing in mind that JS is case sensitive) I've changed the function name to start with a capital "R" - which is the convention for functions intended to be run as constructors.

EDIT: OK, looking at the other answers I can see that just *maybe* I overcomplicated it and *as long as `draw()` doesn't need to access `this`* it would've been fine to just say:

```
this.interval = setInterval(this.draw, 1000);
```

But my point about not giving your constructor and later variable the same name still stands, and I'll leave all the `self` stuff in because it is a technique that you will need if `draw()` does need to access `this`. You would also need to do it that way if you were to add parameters to the `draw()` function.

Comment: `this.draw` won't work if `draw` needs the right `this` inside it, when `draw` is called in the `setInterval(this.draw, 1000)` version, `this` will be `window` inside `draw`. All the `self` stuff is necessary if `draw` uses an instance properties (i.e. if it really is a method rather than just a plain function).

Comment: True. When I added my "edit" I was just looking at `draw` containing "some code" which may not need `this`, but then it probably won't be a very useful method if it doesn't, so...I'll edit my edit...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, removing the quotes and the () worked, then I noticed every time the interval run the variables inside the draw function ponting to this was undefined! then I set everything to self, everything is solved, but, I still don't understand why and how this works, do you mind explaining a bit more please? thanks again. :) oh okay, so this points to window inside the setInterval, HOW WEIRD! anyway is there a better way of doing this, self doesn't look right to me :\

Comment: Well you don't have to call the variable "self", but semantically that's what it is. Some people say "me" or something instead. A _lot_ of people say "that" instead, but I hate "that" because it is wrong semantically ("this" and "that" should not be the same thing). Whatever you name it though the concept is still the best way to do it (that I know of). For more info on how "this" works have a look at [what MDN has to say about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (or just google "javascript this" and see what turns up).

Answer (score 26):

The [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method!

See the following example in **ES6**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

    <script>
        class Circles {
            constructor(canvas, r = 5, color = 'red') {
                this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
                this.width = canvas.width
                this.height = canvas.height

                this.r = r
                this.color = color

                setInterval(
                    this.draw.bind(this),
                    1000
                )
            }

            draw() {
                this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color

                this.ctx.beginPath()
                this.ctx.arc(
                    Math.random() * this.width,
                    Math.random() * this.height,
                    this.r,
                    0,
                    2 * Math.PI
                )

                this.ctx.fill()
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')
        var circles = new Circles(canvas)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @NickSteele Could it be because it causes an extra function invocation before each of the interval's call to `draw()`?  I agree that Yas's solution is more readable.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much.  So glad I found this answer.  I was trying to call setInterval from JavaScript class constructor but none of my class variables were available.  bind() solved it. 